# FPGA output to another FPGA input, 3 meters away

Tags: fpga, buffer

I have one FPGA (Artix-7 XC7A100T-2CSG324C) connected by a PCB trace to another FPGA (Artix-7 XC7A100T-2CSG324C.)

The PCB trace is 3.4 meters long, 0.154mm wide, 0.185mm high from GND plane. The dielectric between signal and ground planes has Dk=3.6 and height of 0.15mm, and a 0.035mm trace height.

This signal is on its own separate layer. Above is a power plane and below is a ground plane. On the same layer, there are ~4 other signals similar to the one discussed here. Additionally, there is a LVDS signal (1 MHz) that is separated from these signals by a GND infill on the  same layer.

I want to know if I switch the FPGA output to a HIGH (3.3V), would the other FPGA be able to see the HIGH (3.3V)? In the end, I am looking at something around 9600 bits per second, but if I can operate at a faster frequency then I won't be upset.

Initially thinking through this problem, I imagine that the PCB trace is too long for the HIGH to be seen, so I want to know the best way to make that HIGH seen. I have been looking around and I have seen people talk about buffers. I don't know how to select a buffer and what information is needed when selecting a buffer for this application.

Comment: What frequency or data rate are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TomCarpenter I don't really have a data rate in mind. I would say 9600 bits per second. However, if it can go faster then that would be preferred.

Comment: You have a single PCB that's 3.4 meters? (I realize that with doubling back, the trace can be somewhat longer than the PCB size, but generally not by a factor of 10)

Comment: I haven't done any analysis of those trace dimensions, but given that FPGA digital pins have nice high input impedance, your I*R voltage drop should be trivial.  People use 10m and 25m cables to connect circuit boards all the time and really don't start to worry until the switching frequency gets over 10MHz.

Comment: Good detail in the question, upvoted. The signal itself will be fine to travel that distance at the low frequency like 9600 baud UART (4800 Hz max.) you mention. The need for more complex drivers and receivers comes when the signal's not all alone and subject to interference, EMI and so on from nearby souurces. That could be other tracka coupling noise onto it, ground bounce from other loads into the ground network, other nearby equipment and so on. Can you edit your question and describe what else is around, other track frequencies, even aa a simple and broad worst case. Thanks.

Comment: Let me ask you (OP) this.  Why do you think that a PCB trace is too long for the HIGH to be seen?

Comment: You (OP) have a single PCB that is 3.4 meters long?

Comment: Are both FPGAs on the same power & return (ground) system?

Comment: @SteveSh Yes, they are on the same power & return system.

Comment: @trident - That helps.  Is this a source synchronous interface (clock & data sent by the source), or an asynchronous interface (local clock at the receiving end)?

Comment: @SteveSh Asynchronous interface.

Comment: @trident - What type of FPGA output buffer were you planning on using?  LVTTL?  CMOS?  Something else?

Comment: @SteveSh I ended up doing some testing and it works fine without a buffer. Hooked it up to an oscilloscope and the signals look really clean. I assumed that I would need a buffer just because the trace seemed pretty long and I wasn't sure if an FPGA could actually output a signal across 3.5 meters, but it did better than I expected.

Comment: I didn't think you'd have a problem given the information you provided.  That's why I asked why you thought you would have a problem.  DC resistance is not a concern.  Low data rates make this easy.  And with this being an async interface (clocking at the receiver) means that you don't really care about reflections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want to use buffers, get two 3.3V CMOS inverter gates and put them at 1 and 2 meter points from the receiving FPGA (so 2.4 and 1.4 meters from the transmitter). Inverters are simpler and faster gates than non-inverting buffers, and any even number will cancel out the inversion.